# Combination of all parameters in linq

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, optimization

I have the following method in which I need fetch records from database based where all/any one/any combination of parameters equals `true`

```
public IQueryable<Entity> GetMethod(bool param1, bool param2, bool param3, bool param4, bool param5, bool param6, bool param7)
{
     //some logic here
}
```

I would like to use an alternative to nested `if` or `switch`

If anyone can help me. Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please, provide example input/output.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this;

```
public IQueryable<Entity> GetMethod(params bool[] parameters)
{        
     bool anyIsTrue = parameters.Any(p => p); //.Any() will do, but just for clarification
     bool anyIsFalse = pramaters.Any(p => !p);

     bool allAreTrue = parameters.All(p => p);
     bool allAreFalse = parameters.All(p => !p);

     //rest of logic
}
```

- [Read some more about LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)
- [Read some more about `params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/w5zay9db.aspx)